# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <GKModalRootViewController: 0xb7e450>

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c++, game-center

I give up on that point, I just can't figure out what is wrong and where...
Here is the problem: in my iPhone application using Cocos2d, I configured autorotation through a viewController; however, since, when Game center opens its view as the user taps on "Create new account" during the authentication, this view does not receive any touch, but the touch go to the game's view (which is hidden under the Game center view).

I have tried everything I thought about, but since I did not find any callback about this Game Center View, it is hard to find a way to correct this...

Here is the initialization of the game's view:

```
// Init the UI View Controller
// 
viewController = [[SQViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

EAGLView *view = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds] pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 depthFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES];
[director setOpenGLView:view];

[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];

[view removeFromSuperview];
[viewController setView:view];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I have tried many other things, commented every single line in this code, tried some others (such as setHidden:NO, bringSubviewToFront...), but the only results I could get were:
- Game display ok, Game Center ok, but no autorotate
- Game displayed in portrait (the view controller only allow landscape modes), Game Center ok, no autorotate
- Game not displayed (black screen), Game Center ok

And no way to make it all work together... The only clue I have is the title of this topic, "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ." But since I do not call the Game Center view myself, I don't know what to do with this...

Anyone, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem while displaying game center leaderboards in my cocos2d built App ever since moving up to iOS 5.0.  I've seen references elsewhere to this being caused by a sub viewcontroller losing focus on the parent viewcontroller, but I've been unable to verify that or get this resolved in my app either.

Good news is that I've run this thru instruments - No Memory Leaks.  Also executed the same action repetitively with no apparent failures or ill effects.

So while this message is an annoyance, it doesn't appear (at least for now) to adversely affect the App.

Answer (score 0):

This Error occurs when you try to push a viewController before previous ViewController is finished . Means you are trying to push 2 ViewControllers at the same time.